# Prove that the sequence $(x_n)$ is monotone increasing, for $x_1=1, x_{n+1}=(2+x_n)^{1/2}$

Tags: analysis, proof-writing, induction, monotone-functions

I proved that the sequence is bounded and that its limit is 2, but how do I prove by induction that it is monotone increasing? i.e. that $x_{n+1} \ge x_n$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you said$,\quad x_{n}< 2$
$$x_{n+ 1}^{2}- x_{n}^{2}= 2+ x_{n}- x_{n}^{2}> 2+ x_{n}- 2x_{n}> 0$$

Comment: Anh đang học thôi em.

Comment: Anh k rành về mảng tổ hợp, đề của em ở bài kia thật sự ko rõ ràng. Ví dụ như ràng buộc của các cách xếp cặp là gì? Em muốn hỏi gì? Anh k hiểu lắm.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The function $f(x) = \sqrt{x+2}$ has derivative $f’(x) > 0$.